Flutter RIverpod; How to update UI from Search results
Iam using a defaultProvider = ref.watch(defaultProvider) which is a FutureProvider to fetch data from an api source and using the result to populate aListView.Builder using
ref.watch(countryProvider).when(
data: (userData) {
List<Article> itemList=
userData.map((e) => e).toList();
return <Widget>(//using itemList[index].data here )
error:(){},
loading(){}
)

how to repopulate this view with the search results from the  ref.read(searchProvider(value)); which is another FutureProvider ? Both returns a type List<CustomType> ? When the app loads it has data from defaultProvider and should replace it with results from Search.
final defaultProvider= FutureProvider<List<CustomType>>((ref) =>
    APIService(('queryparam', 'value'), apiUrl: URLConstants().urlType)
        .getData());


The counterprovider must be a notifier, i.e. It should extends _$CounterProvider and defines the build() method inside It (see the riverpod  doc async notifier
Then when another provider loads new data, It should make something like:
ref.watch(counterprovidernlNotifier).reloadData(....);

In the reload data() It should update ita internal state and Riverpod Will update the view.
The state Is and AsyncValue object, and you should make:
state = const AsyncValue.loading()

Before loading data.
Tò load data something like:
state = await AsyncValue.guard(() async { 
Final myData =await _loadMyData(...); 
Return myData;  });

Thus would refresh the provider
